# Reuse stored procedure result in linq to sql in Code First

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want to get a `Stored Procedure` query

```
var labratorySerialFinalResult = repository.UoW.Orm.Database.SqlQuery<SPLabratorySerialFinalResult>("EXECUTE LabratorySerialFinalResult @OrderNo='" + project.OrderNumber + "'")
```

and use the result like:

```
 var result = projSerials.Where(x =>!labratorySerialFinalResult.Any(v => v.SerialNo == x.SerialNo)
.Union(labratorySerialFinalResult.Where(c => c.FinalResult == "Reject");
```

But gets me the following exception:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type SPLabratorySerialFinalResult Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var labratorySerialFinalResult = repository.UoW.Orm.Database.SqlQuery<SPLabratorySerialFinalResult>("EXECUTE LabratorySerialFinalResult @OrderNo='" + project.OrderNumber + "'").AsEnumerable();

var result = projSerials.AsEnumerable().Where(x =>!labratorySerialFinalResult.Any(v => v.SerialNo == x.SerialNo)
          .Union(labratorySerialFinalResult.Where(c => c.FinalResult == "Reject");
```

[Referencing Non-Scalar Variables Not Supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#RefNonScalarClosures)

> Referencing a non-scalar variables, such as an entity, in a query is
>   not supported. When such a query executes, a NotSupportedException
>   exception is thrown with a message that states "Unable to create a
>   constant value of type EntityType. Only primitive types ('such as
>   Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."

Comment: thanks, but I have a long query that reuses the SP result multiple times , and I loose lots of performance this way ...